# Где искать ответы сложные вопросы, на которые НИКТО не отвечает?

Tags: обсуждение, нытьё

Это даже не столько про SO или ruSO, сколько нытьё про жизнь.

Я никогда не была, как новички на данном сайте. Когда несколько лет назад начинала программировать, у меня были контакты пары опытных специалистов. Вопросов возникало много, но я поставила себе правило, задавать их только если за неделю не смогу найти решение сама. И почти всегда находила. Где-то раз в несколько месяцев всё-таки задавала вопросы, скорее общего характера, посоветовать, каким путём лучше реализовать ту или иную задачу, что изучать (кажется, большую часть тех вопросов здесь бы забанили). Всегда получала понятные и развёрнутые ответы. И жизнь была прекрасна.

Но потом, где-то полгода назад, всё изменилось. Я стала из раза в раз получать ответы из серии "это уже слишком частный вопрос", советую поискать там-то там-то (а я там уже искала). В том числе посоветовали обратиться на SO. И тут начался какой-то ад. У меня к этому времени уже несколько собственных реальных проектов, которые надо поддерживать. И ими пользуются реальные люди. И тут что-то не работает/не получается. Я пишу на ruSO, но реакция нулевая. Я спрашиваю буквально всех своих преподавателей, однокурсников и вообще всех, где хоть какой-то шанс есть, в том числе платно. Либо люди начинают восхищаться моей работой, а по проблеме ничего сказать не могут, либо просто игнор, а преподаватели в вузе ещё очень любят отправлять друг к другу под предлогом "он это лучше знает". Я покупаю книги и курсы, но нахожу там только то, что и так знаю. И так я хожу в агонии со своим вопросом, а пользователи моих систем в этот момент изводят вопросами, когда оно уже заработает.

Если конкретно по ruSO, то я порой даже нахожу тут вопросы, похожие на мои по содержанию. И они тоже с нулевой активностью, максимум пара человек грустит в комментах, что они аж конкурс объявили, а толку никакого. И я понимаю, что конкурс объявлять бесполезно. Или понимаю, что задавать бесполезно, потому что время на оформление потратишь, а реакция будет нулевая. (сейчас у меня 3 очень активных проблемы, которые даже не буду пытаться задавать)
И создается ощущение, что здесь знаний то особо никаких. В основном пункт сбора новичков для отправки в документацию. Ну ещё иногда кто-то с большим рейтингом что-то пишет, сам же отвечает, и получает ещё больше рейтинга. Но это всегда что-то простое. **А на не простое где ответы искать?**
Игра какая-то получается, а не жизнь. Соревнование, кто больше рейтинга наберет и кто больше новичков отправит в документацию.

Интересно, я сейчас прохожу какую-то нормальную стадию развития программиста и следующая стадия - это когда все ответы знаешь, но ни с кем ими не делишься, или уже что-то пошло не так, и обычно у людей моих проблем не возникает?

Comment: "Не на простое" -- OK, из какой хоть области  ваши непростые вопросы? (а так, да, трудно не согласиться, что тут не помешал бы раздел, куда не особо лезут пуристы и гда можно попытаться пообщаться на любые IT-темы)

Comment: JS в основном. Самое больное, я уже пару месяцев пытаюсь разобраться с видеозвонками для нескольких человек. Писала для браузера, используя peerjs, и почти всё работает, только не работает если слабый интернет (логично), но я не могу найти способ сообщить пользователю, что он не в конфе. И ещё не работает если включаться из транспорта даже с хорошим 4G. Но при этом если просто ip менять, то работает. Ещё пытаюсь реализовать авторизацию на passportjs, с двумя стратегиями одновременно local с сессиями и jwt без сессий, чтобы по всем параметрам хорошо было. Ещё производительность RN волнует.

Comment: К сожалению, javascript и браузеры, это не ко мне

Comment: На английском SO попробуйте.

Comment: Говорите с живыми людьми, со специалистами. Отвечать на ru.SO люди (за очень редким исключением) идут, если видят интересный и несложный (для них) вопрос.

Comment: Да, это действительно нытьё про жизнь. Выход как решить свою проблему ,  всегда находить можно,   SO или кто либо, не решает проблемы любого характера в выполнении любого проекта. Это ваш проект, и никто не знает какая там архитектура и намерения, и никто здесь не должен вникать в любой проект любого человека.  Еще нужно  разделять сложные вопросы и вопросы, ответ которых сложно и очень долго сочинять, и что писать намного дольше, чем  рассказывать. Часто бывают вопросы, ответы на которых легче получать в живую(не по интернету)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan на счёт долго отвечать, тоже интересная тема. Я, когда сама отвечала на вопросы, сталкивалась с тем, что вроде всё разжевала, а человек в ответ готовый код просит, дала готовый код, он заработал, но выявилась следующая проблема, и он опять что-то просит и тд. Но конкретно я не ожидаю получать здесь длинных разъяснений. Достаточно "Проверьте то и то, попробуйте это" - в одно предложение, не займёт много времени, и дальше я сама разберусь, что это и как это сделать. Просто иногда бываю в тупике... Возможно, авторам вопросов следует где-то указывать, что они хотят видеть в ответе.

Comment: Вам правильно говорят, ищите ответы не только в русскоязычном сегменте интернета. Рукомьюнити маленькое, хотя и кажется мощным. Если выйдете на англоязычную SO или начнете гуглить на английском - что-то да и найдется (уже пару лет так делаю, получается намного проще доходить до нужной информации). Опять же, по какой-то причине на англоязычной SO более охотно отвечают на сложные вопросы.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar я это понимаю. Гуглю и так в основном на английском (у меня по статистике гугла 85% запросов англоязычные), часто находится что-то. Но задавать вопросы на enSO опасаюсь, как бы не закидали тухлыми помидорами из-за орфографии. Потому что искать и читать - это одно, а нормально писать сложнее. Плюс, писали уже, исходный код смотреть тоже  очень помогает.

Comment: @Hat Там обычно не закидывают (ну или поправят на худой конец). Так что ничего страшного в этом нет, главное, чтобы вопрос был составлен правильно

Comment: Не знаю как в ваших тегах, но в С/С++ разница между ruSO и enSO огромная. У нас была пара действительно продвинутых участников, но они все закончились. А на enSO таких людей с дюжину.

Comment: @Hat Не надо ничего стесняться, будут ошибки - исправят, заодно и английский подтянете

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да во всех тегах разница огромная, как может быть по-другому?

Comment: @Hat по поводу написания на английском, я работаю с американцами, и нашёл как можно писать весьма понятно с помощью использования двух инструментов одновременно: Grammarly и Google Translate. Открываю Google Translate и пишу на английском и проверяю что переводится на русский, то что я имею ввиду. А орфографию и грамматику контролирует браузерное расширение от Грэмэрли. Оно правда предлагает ещё купить стилистические подсказки, но это вовсе не необходимо. Сейчас из РФ его всё равно сложно купить. Да, кстати, они забанили российские айпи с марта 2022, но это решается либо VPN, либо аналогами.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `У нас была пара действительно продвинутых участников, но они все закончились.` вот сейчас обидно было 

Comment: @tym32167 Вас в тегах C/C++ я вообще не запомнил, без обид. :Р

Comment: @HolyBlackCat мой косяк, я не понял, что речь про теги 

Answer (score 22, accepted):

StackOverflow - это всего-лишь справочник наиболее известных проблем и решений, с дополнительной возможностью описать свою проблему и случайно попасть на специалиста, который ее решил.

Ладно, это не точная формулировка, это отсебятина. Но, согласитесь, если принять ее, это может помочь не только избавиться от чувства разочарования но и разобраться как эффективно использовать StackOverflow для повседневных нужд.

Для решения всех остальных проблем есть только один путь - через понимание механизма проблемы (что происходит, почему это происходит, как должно происходить на самом деле). Для этого, прежде всего, надо на фундаментальном уровне понимать принципы по которым устроена платформа для которой вы разрабатываете, язык, на котором вы разрабатываете, библиотека, с помощью которой вы разрабатываете (в плоть до изучения ее исходного кода).

Если нет рядом человека, у которого есть возможность и желание вникнуть в вашу проблему, решение придется искать самостоятельно.

Вот почему важно, помимо изучения популярных фреймворков, уделять время изучению устройства процессора, операционной системы, браузера. Эти, на первый взгляд ненужные знания, делают свою незаметную работу, позволяя взглянуть на проблему под правильным углом, увидеть возможные направления к решению и методично их прорабатывать, вместо слепого тыканья наугад. Скажу больше, имея фундаментальные знания даже гуглить становится проще :-)

> Интересно, я сейчас прохожу какую-то нормальную стадию развития программиста и следующая стадия - это когда все ответы знаешь, но ни с кем ими не делишься, или уже что-то пошло не так, и обычно у людей моих проблем не возникает?

В интернете ходит забавная иллюстрация эффекта Данинга-Крюгера: [image].
Вероятно, вы на пути к стадии Эксперт (то есть в на самом дне ямы страданий) :-)

Answer (score 20):

Тоже сталкивался с этой проблемой.

0. Надо сделать [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
1. Если вопрос достаточно сложный, то ответить на него может гораздо меньше людей. Не факт, что они его увидят. Можно попробовать несколько раз немного подредактировать вопрос (только не злоупотреблять), чтобы он всплыл на главной. И можно попробовать объявить конкурс, хотя не факт, что это поможет.
2. Надо стараться задать вопрос так, чтобы было не лень его читать. А ещё так, чтобы после прочтения надо было как можно меньше повторять тому, кто захочет на него ответить. Если вопрос требует собрать 10 фрагментов кода воедино, да ещё добавить каких-то файлов, то вероятность, что всё это захотят сделать, резко падает. Зато возрастает вероятность того, что напишут какую-то идею, которую ты уже пробовала.

   Если кто-то пишет простыню кода, то есть вероятность, что я прочитаю просто текст, проигнорирую код и отвечу другим кодом. На простые вопросы это сработает. На сложные, когда, к тому же, проблему не описали в тексте вообще, ты получаешь совершенно бесполезный ответ.
3. На enSO аудитория гораздо больше, чем тут, так что получить там ответ вероятнее. Можно задать на обоих языках и добавить ссылки друг на друга (кстати, добавление ссылки на перевод - это тоже редактирование вопроса).
4. Надо стараться спрашивать именно то, что ты хочешь узнать.

---

А вот что касается твоих вопросов, то есть сомнения:

1. [Вопрос про кэш](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1393033/178988)

   Непонятно, как воспроизводится. Кэширование не работает рандомно - должно либо не работать всегда, либо работать всегда. Если не работает рандомно, то без внятного описания того, как всё устроено и подключается, какие заголовки кэширования выставлены и какие запросы посылаются браузером, ответить почти невозможно. Только если вдруг кто-то совершенно случайно сталкивался с той же проблемой.

   При этом вопрос сформулирован не как "как правильно настроить кэширование?" (кстати, на эту тему есть полно статей), а "почему работает рандомно?", на что ответить нереально.
2. [Удалённый вопрос про pm2 watch](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1392931/178988)

   Собственно, в вопросе код, который должен работать. Никто не поможет, если проблема решается перезапуском или перезагрузкой, а весь код верный. Такие штуки надо проверять самостоятельно.

   А уж если бы перезапуск не помог, то очевидно, что в вопросе недостаточно данных, поскольку приведённый код верный. И надо гадать в сторону "а используется ли вообще этот файл конфига", а не патчит ли какой-нибудь postinstall-скрипт устанавливаемые модули и другую подобную дичь.
3. [Вопрос про docx-файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1391060/178988)

   Вероятность получить ответ "это невозможно" в большинстве случаев низкая. Только если кто-то полностью уверен, потому что идеально знает, что делает. Ну или его попросили ответить.

   Кстати, такой вопрос можно было бы задать на гитхабе самой библиотеки, где я и нагуглил ответ трёхлетней давности, что это не поддерживается.

   В целом вопрос составлен хорошо, но требует много усилий, чтобы попробовать сделать.
4. [Вопрос про задержку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1321828/178988)

   В твоём ответе говорится о проблемах из-за socket.io, которого даже нет в вопросе. Ну и как об этом надо было догадаться?

   Берёшь проект, выкидываешь из него постепенно всё, пока проблема не исчезнет и находишь конкретное место. Если всё ещё непонятно, почему так, задаёшь вопрос, указывая именно на него. [Минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

На enSO у тебя вопросов вообще нет. Может есть удалённые, но я их только по прямой ссылке могу смотреть.

Comment: Ну 1 и 2 это даже не совсем вопросы. Я знала, где искать ответ, просто пыталась обнаружить тот порог на этом сайте, с которого хоть один коммент появится или закрытие с причиной или реакция какая-то :) 4 - аж 7 месяцев назад, я тогда другим человеком была))) Это я скорее про чужие вопросы писала. Я прежде чем задавать, очень долго ищу на SO и ruSO, нахожу и понимаю, что задавать бессмысленно

Comment: в 4 собственно причина проблемы так и была мною обнаружена, как вы написали

Comment: @Hat, ну значит даже в этом вопросе нет примеров, куда смотреть ;)

Comment: @Hat, чем "красивее" и проще библиотека, тем меньше в ней можно сделать по сравнению с более низкоуровневыми библиотеками. Ну а преподы разные бывают.

Comment: @Hat, так что, какие вопросы глянуть?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1044895/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-node-js-passport-facebook-jwtwebtoken-%d0%b2-rest-api-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8 это сегодня видела, тут у человека на мой взгляд нагромождение кода, возможно поэтому не отвечают. Но тема интересная, потому что когда-то также я не могла соединить гугл с jwt

Comment: А вообще как можно правильно формулировать вопросы, если мне готовый код в ответе вообще не нужен, мне нужно общее понимание и направление, где искать? Такое часто закрывают из-за "основано на мнениях"

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1394488/websocket-peerjs-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-401-unauthorized-%d0%b2-console-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80#comment2478468_1394488 А это я отслеживаю, жду, вдруг напишут про правильную реализацию способа, который у меня не получился (в последних комментариях)

Answer (score 11):

Решение сложного вопроса требует много времени. Отвечая бесплатно, человек хочет иметь хоть какую-то уверенность, что его ответ не канет в пустоту, что его затраты времени действительно помогут кому-то.

Авторы большинства вопросов совершенно не проявляют заинтересованность в получении ответов. Объясню, что я имею в виду.

Вопрос сложный, поэтому чаще всего его трудно понять сходу. Автору пишут комментарии, прося уточнить непонятные моменты. Автор никак не реагирует на комментарии. Значит автору ответ не нужен?

На вопрос пишут ответы. Зачастую неполные, решающие лишь часть проблемы. Автор никак не реагирует на них, не уточняет, какую часть проблемы он смог решить с помощью этих ответов, а что осталось нерешённым. Значит автору ответ не нужен?

Возможно, автор уже сам нашёл решение. Так опубликуй его!
Возможно, автору уже не нужно решение (пошли другим путём; отказались от задания; в конце концов автора уволили за профнепригодность) - ну так напиши об этом, чтобы люди не тратили своё время.

А если решение действительно нужно, то дайте об этом знать: регулярно (скажем, раз в день-два) обновляйте вопрос (достаточно один символ изменить), чтобы он появлялся на главной странице сайта. Показывайте свои попытки решения (если они есть). Уточняйте непонятные места в ответ на комментарии. Просто просите помощи, давая понять, что труды отвечающих не останутся незамеченными.

Я это всё пишу по собственному опыту. У меня и сейчас висят в браузере несколько открытых вопросов, на которые я мог бы ответить (но нужно затратить прилично времени на каждый из них). Этим вопросам уже несколько дней. Когда я их увидел, я не мог ответить сразу, был занят. Сейчас появилось время, вернулся к ним: а там никакой реакции авторов на комментарии с просьбами уточнить непонятные моменты. Соответственно, у меня пропадает желание тратить время на ответы.

Comment: Вы ещё держите вкладки =) У меня давно подход - написал коммент уточняющий и забыл. Надо будет автору - пинганет меня, нет так нет.

Answer (score 7):

Поздравляю, вы растете в профессиональном плане.

Чем сильнее вы прогрессируете в карьере, тем сложнее ваши вопросы. А ответы на сложные вопросы по определению сложнее знать наперед и тем более написать. Добро пожаловать в реальный мир, где ответы на многие вопросы приходится искать или изобретать самому. Это знает любой профессионал.

Вот поглядите высокореповых участников [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) и оцените распределение вопросов, что они задали и ответов. В большинстве случаев ответов будет на порядок больше, чем вопросов. Просто потому, что если сюда пришел уже опытный участник, то он уже привык сам искать или изобретать ответы на свои вопросы. Вот и вся магия.

С опытом будет ещё интересней. Как насчет вопросов, ответов на которые нет в природе? Это вас тоже ждет впереди.

Потому факт, что на ваш вопрос пришло мало людей, никак не касается сайта или участников. Это все специфика ваших вопросов.

Так что привыкайте, что SO - это не сервис ответов на ваши вопросы, коим он никогда не был. Это БД самых распространенных вопросов/ответов. Специалистов по любой кнопке любого приложения, что вы используете, тут нет.

Что касается вашего пассажа типа `И создается ощущение, что здесь знаний то особо никаких. В основном пункт сбора новичков для отправки в документацию.` - вы часть сообщества, у вас есть сложные ответы не для новичков?  У меня есть - можете поглядеть мои ответы и мои вопросы. Вы здесь, с нами, потому если вас не устраивает качество местных вопросов или ответов - действуйте, меняйте ситуацию. Я гляжу, у вас всего 60 комментариев в профиле. У меня 10+ тысяч. И да, если ответ есть в документации, то я поясняю это и даю ссылку. Поотвечайте хотя бы на 20-30 подобных вопросов и сами поймете, что тут ничего нет плохого.

То, что простых вопросов для новичков тут большинство - это очевидно, ведь новички по определению задают больше вопросов и количество новичков гораздо больше, чем опытных профи. Это я не только про наше сообщество, а вообще.

`А на не простое где ответы искать?`

- у специалистов по профилю
- придумывать ответы самому
- искать везде, где только можно

`Соревнование, кто больше рейтинга наберет и кто больше новичков отправит в документацию.` - я приму этот высокомерный пассаж как состояние аффекта. Вы видите только то, что хотите видеть. Вы искали [интересные вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1012399/179763)? Я думаю, что нет. Вы искали [интересные ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/768244/179763)? Тоже наверное нет. Вы просто ищите рутинные вопросы, коих большинство, но не ищите действительно стоящие вопросы и ответы к ним. И делаете какие-то выводы. Можете найти и то и другое в моем профиле - там достаточно.

По поводу "набивания рейтинга", как только вы наберете определенный рейтинг (это может быть и 1000, и 10 000 или 20 000), вам, как и большинству высокореповых участников, станет абсолютно фиолетово, добавится к вашим 10к рейтинга ещё 15 или нет.

Если хотите, чтобы SO был полон сложных вопросов и ответов - то вы и есть человек, который этого может добиться. Нет тут такого, что "сообщество набивателей рейтинга и я отдельно от него". Вы тут, значит, вы уже часть сообщества, так же как я или любой другой участник. И сообщество будет таким, каким мы его сделаем.

А ваша боль по поводу сложных вопросов без внимания - привыкайте. Сообщество тут не при чем. Это просто закон природы - чем сложнее вопрос, тем сложнее найти на него ответ.

Answer (score 5):

Как по мне нужно просто принять как данность, что никто не будет за вас искать решения, на реально сложные вопросы. Никто не будет жертвовать своим временем, чтобы глубоко копать вашу проблему. А многие вопросы требуют именно этого, не на все вопросы можно ответить сходу. Поэтому надо просто спокойно к этому относиться. Получили решение - радуйтесь, не получили - ищите сами.

P.S. Как бы глупо не звучало, возможно стоит добавить вознаграждение не только баллами, но и денежное. Тогда у других пользователей появится стимул копать глубже

Comment: За денежным вознаграждением надо идти на фриланс биржу. Наш сайт не является такой и цели сайта тоже никак не совпадают с этой идеей.

Comment: Тут из-за плюсиков то драмы нешуточные, а вы еще предлагаете керосинчику подлить